# tried valid URL with no result

Tags: sbt

sbt is reporting:

[warn] ==== teleal-repo: tried
[warn]   http://teleal.org/m2/org/teleal/cling/cling-core/1.0.4/cling-core-1.0.4.pom

and then complaining that this depdency is unresolved.

Only problem is that's a valid URI.  Any idea why SBT would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your ivy cache (~/.ivy2/cache) and doing the clean build (sbt clean update compile)